# Error compiling bpy

Tags: python, linux, compile

I've been following this tutorial to build the [bpy module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule)

However, I get an error at the end of `make bpy`:

```bash
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.a(pngerror.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'stderr' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [source/creator/CMakeFiles/blender.dir/build.make:498: bin/bpy.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7410: source/creator/CMakeFiles/blender.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
make: *** [GNUmakefile:327: all] Error 2
```

How do I solve this? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69683755/libpng-apngerror-o-requires-dynamic-r-x86-64-pc32-reloc-against-stderr) which was very vague and didn't help much. I've added

```
CFLAGS = -fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -g
```

to GNUmakefile and changed the following line under "Build Blender"

```
$(BUILD_COMMAND) -C "$(BUILD_DIR)" -j $(NPROCS) install
```

to

```
$(BUILD_COMMAND) $(CFLAGS) -C "$(BUILD_DIR)" -j $(NPROCS) install
```

to no avail.

Comment: i think questions pertaining to compiling blender and/or modules are off-topic in this forum. you will need to ask at devtalk.blender.org

Comment: I don't think they are off-topic according to the site rules, however there are very little actual Blender C programmers that visit this site so the questions often remain unanswered and are better suited for devtalk :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on Linux. Have you checked that you are using the latest commit and library versions by running `make update` first?